# Modify properties file with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, properties, visualization

I have a properties file controlling the behavior of some visualizations.
If i have some buttons or dropdowns in my visualizaiton, is it possible to use javascript to modify the properties file?

The idea is something I like, I have a dropdown with available fields to visualize and selecting a value in the dropdown modifies the properties file.

Modifying properties file in java is easy, but I don't know about javascript

Comment: Nope, you'll have to make an AJAX call to your Java server, where Java will modify the Properties file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a properties file on your server, you will need to do so with serverside code.  You can use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to run javascript on the server, allowing you to use it to modify serverside files.  The [`fs` module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) provides functions to read and write to files.  But if you're running your JS in the browser you will not be able to directly modify a serverside file.

If you are making the call from the browser, the correct method is to make an ajax call to your serverside code (could be java, php, javascript using NodeJS, etc) and modify the file with that code.

Comment: hmm i see makes sense. i understood that i couldn't modify it directly, but now i get the idea a bit more. is there some guide/example you could point me to of making an ajax call to java code with javascript?

Comment: @lemonio a quick google brings up this: http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/ which seems pretty reasonable.  If the verbose syntax on the JS side looks scary to you, you can also use jQuery's ajax functions to simplify that end of things: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/